# moving my site to the new domain with updraft plus backup

Tags: wordpress, plugins, migration, backup, restore

I would like to move the site from domain1.com to domain2.com with wordpress. The problem is that I have only the backup I have made before on domain1.com using updraftplus plugin.

Now the plugin shows me the message that I should have made a migration, not the backup.

I have noticed that in the backup there are many lines with '...domain1.com...'. I have replaced every existing string ('...domain1.com...') to '...domain2.com...'. The problem still exists. Plugin somehow recognize that the backup is made from the 'domain1.com'.

Is this possible now to restore the site from the backup I have ?

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://updraftplus.com/migrator/) yet?

Comment: Yes, but I dont want to pay for it. I was wondering if there is some way to restore it manually.